# Check if pyodbc connection is open or closed

Tags: python, mysql, odbc, pyodbc

I often get this error: `ProgrammingError: The cursor's connection has been closed.`

Is there a way to check whether the connection I am using has been closed before I attempt to execute a query?

I'm thinking of writing a wrapper to execute queries. First it would check whether the connection is closed, if it is, it would reconnect. Is this an advisable way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wrapper is a good idea but I don't know any API to reliably check whether the connection is closed or not.

So the solution would be something along these lines:

```
for retry in range(3):
    try:
        ... execute query ...
        return # Stop on success
    except e:
        if is_connection_broken_error(e):
             reconnect()
             continue
        raise

raise # throw if the retry fails too often
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to check if you can get a cursor (many times that's what you want from a connection anyway) and re-initialize the connection otherwise. It will look something like this:

```
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except e:
    if e.__class__ == pyodbc.ProgrammingError:        
        conn == reinit()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: this is not a good idea.  pyodbc.ProgrammingError is raised in a lot of situation.  Using this you will eat lots of important error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing). Use what you need and catch the exception. 99% of the time it is likely to be OK.