# Casting a custom object to another custom object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, casting

Is it possible to cast a custom object into another custom object in Javascript? 
For example, in the Java implementation of the code I am trying to convert into Javascript, they have done the following:

```
return ((TimeSeriesPoint)tsArray.get(pointIndex)).get(valueIndex);
```

where `tsArray` is an `ArrayList` and `TimeSeriesPoint` is a custom class for which the implementation exists. Is it possible to perform such casting into `TimeSeriesPoint` in `Javascript`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In javascript there is no type safety for objects as I know. you can assign one object to another without any casting.

Comment: Casting should not be necessary. See [duck typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no types for objects in JavaScript, so there is no casting.

For what you want to do, your `TimeSeriesPoint` constructor should take one point as an *argument* and construct a new object from it, so that you can invoke it like

```
return (new TimeSeriesPoint(tsArray.get(pointIndex)).get(valueIndex);
```

Alternatively, if your points in the array are very similar to timeseries-points (and qualify as them via [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), i.e. have the same instance properties), you could just apply the `TimeSeriesPoint` `get` method on them:

```
return TimeSeriesPoint.prototype.get.call(tsArray.get(pointIndex), valueIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is no type safety for objects as I know. you can assign one object to another without any casting.

Please see below example.

```
var x= []; // x is an array
x = {}; // Now x changes to object
```