# Java threads. Runnable interface

Tags: java

I want to clarify a doubt in multi threading in java.
Cant we create an interface with run() and implement it instead of Runnable interface. Will it work?

Comment: Well how would you expect to pass it to the `Thread` constructor? This is pretty easy to try - so I suggest you delete this question, try it (the research you should do before asking a question), then ask a question if you still need any clarification.

Comment: If you mean create your own interface with a `run()` method that isn't called the common `Runnable` in Java, then you can, except pretty much all of the concurrency libraries won't recognize it. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No it won't work.

Or at least, it won't work unless your interface `implements` the real `Runnable` interface.

Java inheritance is NOT based on duck typing.  Two unrelated interfaces with the same method signatures are not type compatible in the Java type system.

Reference:

- [What is duck typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing)