# How do I ensure parameter is correct type in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and am trying to figure out if there is a way to specify the variable type in a parameter definition.  For example:

```
def function(int(integer))
```

as opposed to:

```
def function(integer)
    int(integer)
```

I know it's not a major difference, but I'm trying to use good programming practices here, and if I'm defining a function with a large number of parameters, it could get messy.

Comment: Nope, there is no type checking in python, are you actually talking type checking or casting from something that can be cast to an int?

Comment: Related: [What's the Canonical Way to Check for Type in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/154156/418413)

Comment: You question leads me to believe you aren't taking a Pythonic approach to solving your problem. Python is dynamically typed and your solution should  be flexible to take advantage of that.

Comment: `isinstance(some_variable, int)`

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: " if I'm defining a function with a large number of parameters" This usually means that the function needs to be refactored because it is doing too many things.

Answer (score 28):

As of Python 3.4 you can add type annotations to a function or method:

```
def function(a: int):
    pass
```

However **these types are not enforced** - you can still call the function with a value that is not an integer.

Furthermore, Python is based on the idea of duck typing so you may sometimes want to accept a variety of types, such as both `int` and `float` for a particular function.

Comment: This answer could be improved by directly addressing the question. As written it seems to bait-and-switch the answer by mentioning something that seems like it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: It's actually 3.5 that type annotation was introduced.

Answer (score 18):

Python uses [Duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing) which means you should not discriminate objects based on what type they are, but based on what attributes and functions they have. This has many advantages which are outside of the scope of this answer.

What you should do instead if you want to add documentation to your function is to use a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

```
def square(x):
    """takes a number and squares it"""
    return x**2
```

and [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

```
def square(x: int) -> int:
    """takes a number and squares it"""
    return x**2
```

if you *really* need to check the arguments given to you, you can do a `hasattr()` to check for the attributes and functions the argument provides. In most situations (including this one) just not checking the type is better

```
def square(x):
    """takes a number and squares it"""
    if not hasattr(x, "__pow__"):
         raise TypeError("unsupported operand:", type(x))

    return x**2
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use the syntax

```
def function(a: int):
    pass
```

mentioned by @SimeonVisser and you have python3.5, you can use the decorator I wrote

```
from typing import get_type_hints

def strict_types(f):
    def type_checker(*args, **kwargs):
        hints = get_type_hints(f)

        all_args = kwargs.copy()
        all_args.update(dict(zip(f.__code__.co_varnames, args)))

        for key in all_args:
            if key in hints:
                if type(all_args[key]) != hints[key]:
                    raise Exception('Type of {} is {} and not {}'.format(key, type(all_args[key]), hints[key]))

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return type_checker
```

while defining functions like that

```
@strict_types
def concatenate_with_spam(text: str) -> str:
    return text + 'spam'
```

and it will raise an exception if the argument passed to your function is of the wrong type.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strict_types.py", line 23, in <module>
    concatenate_with_spam(1)
  File "strict_types.py", line 13, in type_checker
    raise Exception('Type of {} is {} and not {}'.format(key, type(all_args[key]), hints[key]))
Exception: Type of text is <class 'int'> and not <class 'str'>
```

Though I haven't implemented a way to check the type of what you return and this solution won't suit you if you want to check it too.

Comment: I think simple assert statements to assert the type of each param works better!

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't getting more upvotes. It may be not truly pythonic but it's doing exactly what was asked for. I also wrote a decorator myself with this functionality and ended up with pretty much the exact same code as presented here.

Comment: I've been searching high and low for something like this. I ended up writing something not too dissimilar but which would pop in a default value if the argument provided was improper.

Comment: Use [`isinstance(<value>, <type>)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of `type(<value>) == <type>`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def function(integer :int):
    assert isinstance(integer, int), 'your error message'
    print(integer * integer)

>>> function(3)
    9
>>> function('3')
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    function('3')
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 2, in function
    assert isinstance(integer, int), 'your error message'
AssertionError: your error message
```

Comment: please try now I have missed  "isinstance" word in previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of @ilya-peterov's function that includes checking the type of the function's return value:

```
def type_checker(f):
"""
A decorator that verifies if the arguments of a function match the specified type.
@param f: the function
@return:
"""

def checker(*args, **kwargs):
    hints = get_type_hints(f)

    all_args = kwargs.copy()
    all_args.update(dict(zip(f.__code__.co_varnames, args)))

    # Check the args type
    for arg_name, arg_value in all_args.items():
        if arg_name in hints:
            expected_type = hints[arg_name]
            # If Union get values
            if hasattr(expected_type, "__origin__") and expected_type.__origin__ == typing.Union:
                expected_type = expected_type.__args__
            msg = f"The `{arg_name}` parameter in `{f.__name__}` function should be an {expected_type} type. " \
                  f"A {type(arg_value)} type was passed instead."
            assert isinstance(arg_value, expected_type), msg

    output = f(*args, **kwargs)

    # Check the output type if specified
    output_type = hints.get('return', None)
    if output_type:
        msg = f"The `{f.__name__}` function should return a {output_type}, " \
              f"but it's returning a {type(output)} instead. " \
              "Please ensure that the return type matches the expected type."
        assert isinstance(output, output_type), msg
    return output

return checker
```