# specify the type inside a class method

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, readability

What is the pythonic way to properly specify the type of the arguments of a method?

Checking [How do Python functions handle the types of the parameters that you pass in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489669/how-do-python-functions-handle-the-types-of-the-parameters-that-you-pass-in) and [How do I ensure parameter is correct type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684720/how-do-i-ensure-parameter-is-correct-type-in-python) only works for primitive data types.

Consider the minimum following example, where I want to pass an object of same type to the method. This does not work because the method is defined inside the class.

```
class num:
    def __init__(self,val:int) -> None:
        self.x=val
    def print(self,other:num) -> None:
        pass

def main():
    n=num(3)
    n.print()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

```python
class num:
    def __init__(self,val:int) -> None:
        self.x=val
    def print(self,other:'num') -> None:
        pass
```

This works because Python (and any checkers complying to PEP 484) will understand your hint and register it appropriately, this is a common scenario.