# In python statsmodels, finding the standard error of the regression

Tags: python

[According to the docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html), I can find the standard error of the regression by using the scale() class method on a RegressionResults instance.

However, I cannot obtain a RegressionResults instance.

This is what I did:

```
y = foo; X = bar

model = sm.OLS(y, X)

results = model.fit()
```

Looking into object type...

```
print type(results)
```

...returns a RegressionResultsWrapper

```
<class 'statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper'>
```

This "RegressionResultsWrapper" is undocumented, and I cannot find a way to manipulate it. results.scale() fails, and I cannot obtain the information I want.

Further, [the docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit.html) state that .fit() is supposed to return a RegressionResults class instance, but what is returned is the RegressionResultsWrapper as seen above.

Any idea how I can obtain the information on the "standard error of the regression" for this regression model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Python's "[duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing)" convention at work. When the documentation says that `fit()` should return a `RegressionResults` instance, it really means it will return something that is compatible with the public interface of `RegressionResults`. Any of the documented attributes and methods of `RegressionResults` should be accessible from the returned object, in accordance with how they are described in the documentation. And indeed that seems to be the case: if you access `results.scale`, you will get a number. Note that it's not a method; it's an attribute. The error message you get when trying to call it as a method tells you that, if you missed it in the documentation.

It's true that technically they should say that the method returns something *compatible* with `RegressionResults` rather than a `RegressionResults` instance itself, but it's understood by most Python programmers that under normal circumstances, you shouldn't be actually checking the type of the objects you're given.

Comment: Wow thanks David for the perfect answer! I didn't realise that scale is an attribute as well. I spent... almost 2 hours in frustration. You are a lifesaver! :)