# Is there a way to monkey-patch core python class?

Tags: python, class

Is there a way to monkey-patch core python class ?
Something along the lines  :

```
class Boo:
    def is_empty(self) : return not self

list.is_empty = Boo.is_empty
```

> TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'

I don't want to extend it , I want to monkey-patch it.

---

Sorry I meant "monkey-patch".

Comment: What do you mean by "duct type"? Do you mean "monkey-patch"? If so, no, you can't do that.

Comment: @kindall: I think that was a mixup between *duck-type* and *duct tape*.

Comment: If you *do mean monkey-patch*, it's possible, but you've got to understand the CPython internals pretty well: https://gist.github.com/mahmoudimus/295200

Comment: @KenWhite You mean duck tape? :)

Comment: Workaround: `def is_empty(lst): if len(lst) == 0: return True`

Comment: @user1019129 mind accepting my answer, or ask for improvements if there's somthing wrong with it? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean [*monkey patching*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch) instead of [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing), then yes, you can do it with `ctypes` as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested in the comments: https://gist.github.com/mahmoudimus/295200

But even then I'd highly advice against it, since it can break everyone else's code if they import your module. Imagine what would happen if *everyone* started messing with the internals, you couldn't safely import anything anymore!

What you should do instead is subclass the Python classes:

```
class Boo(list):
    def is_empty(self):
        return not self

>>> my_list = Boo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> my_list2 = Boo([])
>>> my_list.is_empty()
False
>>> my_list2.is_empty()
True
>>> my_list2.append(5)
>>> my_list2.is_empty()
False
>>> my_list2
[5]
```