# Assigning strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am following this tutorial to learn javascript, currently at the 33rd video of this tutorial: [EJ media Javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUmBsIzg94g&list=PLr6-GrHUlVf96NLj3PQq-tmEB6woZjwEl&index=22)

The author in his video says, below object is a string object:

```
var hello = "hello world";
```

and some time later, he does below

```
hello = hello.length;
```

I am not able to understand the `hello` state here – is this still a string object (since `hello.length` returns a number and we are storing it in same hello variable and in same scope). Let me know if this is basic, I've tried searching with the terms "java script string assignment", but nothing related came up.

Below is the entire code:

```
var hello = "hello world";
hello = hello.length;
```

Comment: The string value is overwritten by the new assignment, and is now an integer.

Comment: `hello=hello.length`, `hello` is now a number not a string. (Do a type check before and after the assignment: `console.log(typeof hello);` and see what it tells you).

Comment: I have to say just from your example that seems like a really confusing way to teach someone. As others have stated JavaScript is dynamic so doesn't require you to keep a variable a specific type and because of this by setting your variable to an integer the type becomes a number/integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because JavaScript is dynamically and weakly typed language.

- Dynamically typed means that type checking will be carried out at runtime instead of in a compiler.
- Weakly typed refers to the ability to change type on the fly within your code.

Having in mind these properties, then `var hello="hello world";` will define a variable called `hello` with value of type `String` and when you do `hello=hello.length;` then you override `hello` value with `Number` type returned by `hello.length`

```js
var hello = "hello world";

console.log(typeof hello);

hello = hello.length;

console.log(typeof hello);
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript variable types are mutable. There is probably a technical name for this.

You can change the variable type repeatedly.

For instance the most terse way to change a string "1234" to a number type is to do "1234"*1;

Comment: probably duck typing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing

Comment: Actually the most terse way would be +"1234"