# How can duck typing be 'implemented' in a language that doesn't have strong typing

Tags: javascript

I was reading [the exploring ES6 book](http://exploringjs.com/es6/), where at some point the author talks about the history of Javascript:

> ECMAScript 4 was designed by Adobe, Mozilla, Opera, and Google and was
>   a massive upgrade. Its planned feature sets included:
>
> [...]
>
> Evolutionary programming and scripting ([...],duck typing,[...])

But JavaScript does not enforce strong typing. So how can duck typing be **implemented**? Isn't duck typing already in the language?

Doesn't duck typing just mean not enforcing strong typing?

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing

Comment: "Duck typing" is not something you "implement", to me. It's a thing that varies based on a very specific API.