# Error while changing Pandas DataFrame index using map method

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), index = list('abc'), columns = list('wxyz'))
df
   w  x   y   z
a  0  1   2   3
b  4  5   6   7
c  8  9  10  11
```

I know that I can change the index using the map method in this way.

```
df.index.map(str.upper)
```

Wondered if I could change the Index in this way.

```
df.index.map(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

But, when I ran the code, I got the following error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can someone explain the syntactical difference and the reason for the error.

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase` is not a function, it's just a string with `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` value

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the second one? An upper case to lower case mapping?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntactical difference. There is a difference in the type of object you are using as a parameter to [`pandas.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Index.map.html). The docs make clear what's permitted:

> Index.**map**(*mapper*)
>       Apply mapper function to an index.
>
> **mapper** : *callable*
>      Function to be applied.

In general, it's a better idea to test whether an object is callable than to test whether it's a function. See [What is duck typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing) for the rationale.

In this case, `str.upper` is a callable, while `string.ascii_lowercase` is a string. To confirm this, you can use [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#callable) (Python 3.2+):

```
callable(str.upper)               # True
callable(string.ascii_lowercase)  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` package is mostly deprecated.

```
import string 

string.__doc__

"A collection of string operations (most are no longer used).
\n\nWarning: most of the code you see here isn't normally used nowadays [...]
```

The builtin `str` allows you to do most operations. As stated by Zero string.ascii_lowercase just gives you the alphabet in lowercase.

If what you want to achieve is to put your DataFrame index in lowercase, then you should do `df.index.map(str.lower)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), index = list('ABC'), columns = list('wxyz'))
df.index.map(str.lower)
   w  x   y   z
a  0  1   2   3
b  4  5   6   7
c  8  9  10  11
```