# In a new class, how to avoid calling an instance of another class?

Tags: python

Essentially, this is what I currently have:

In script1 I have this:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,name,school):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
```

In script2 I have this:

```
class Teacher(object):
    def __init__(self,name,school):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
```

And in script3, I define the instances and check if the schools match:

```
student1=Student("Alex","Highschool")
teacher1=Teacher("Mary","Highschool")

if student1.school == teacher1.school:
    print("yes")
```

However I would like to incorporate checking if the schools matched in either script1 or script2. This is what I have tried:

```
class Teacher(object):
    def __init__(self,name,school):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
    def _check_if_school_matches(self,Student()):
        if self.school == Student.school:
            print("yes")
```

But of course I get a `SyntaxError`, and I can't say `_check_if_school_matches(self,student1)` because `student1` is not defined yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new instance of `Student` in that method's argument list. Change that to:

```
def _check_if_school_matches(self, student):
    if self.school == student.school:
        print("yes")
```

So now if you call that method on `teacher1` with the `student1` instance, it prints "yes"

```
student1=Student("Alex", "Highschool")
teacher1=Teacher("Mary", "Highschool")

teacher1._check_if_school_matches(student1) # yes
```

[What is duck typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much!