# Is there a canonical “isinstance” implementation for typing types?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, pydantic

You can’t use [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) types like `Dict[str, int]` in an `isinstance` check:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:28)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from typing import Dict

In [2]: myvar = {"a": 1}

In [3]: isinstance(myvar, Dict[str, int])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a8fee57141ae> in <module>
----> 1 isinstance(myvar, Dict[str, int])
```

However any library that does type-checking needs to be able to do something kind of like `isinstance(myvar, Dict[str, int])` (...I realise it should be called something different than `isinstance`, that this is not the exactly same thing)

I feel like the equivalent function that works for typing must exist somewhere, maybe in [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/) project? (but there’s a lot of complicated code in there and I couldn’t find it so far)

There are plenty of projects besides mypy which need this, libraries like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) for example, and AFAICT they all have complicated hand-rolled implementations and it seems like there are lots of edge cases (or just… ‘cases’) which have to be enumerated and covered. This leads to bugs/limited type recognition e.g. https://github.com/bloomberg/attrs-strict/issues/27

It seems like there is a need for a canonical implementation of this functionality. Does one exist already somewhere that I haven’t found?

**I give you a motivating example from the Python stdlib:**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

> For functions annotated with types, the decorator will infer the type of the first argument automatically:

```
>>> @fun.register
... def _(arg: int, verbose=False):
...     if verbose:
...         print("Strength in numbers, eh?", end=" ")
...     print(arg)
...
>>> @fun.register
... def _(arg: list, verbose=False):
...     if verbose:
...         print("Enumerate this:")
...     for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
...         print(i, elem)
```

Well that's pretty cool. But it's cheating, because these days generally we wouldn't annotate the second function using `list` builtin, but rather something like `List[str]`... and that doesn't work, because `singledispatch` is just doing a naive `isinstance` check, and that can't handle typing generics. So `singledispatch` doesn't really support dispatch by type-annotation like it claims to.

Comment: mypy is all about static checks. The whole `typing` system is really geared towards static checks - runtime introspection seems like an afterthought. Even things like `typing.get_args` that you'd expect to be in from day 1 took until Python 3.8 to be introduced. That was over 4 years after `typing` itself went in in Python 3.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a value matches a type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503673/how-do-i-check-if-a-value-matches-a-type-in-python)

Comment: @Georgy kind of, yes, in that there is seemingly no good answer, just various people struggling against the lack of support for this kind of checking in the core `typing` library. Here is another related question with some good answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563546/validating-detailed-types-in-python-dataclasses/50622643

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no canonical check of this sort. As the commenter says, typing was introduced for static type checks, and i think many of the core developers think it should stay like that.

The nearest thing I can think of is pydantic's `parse_obj_as`. It's different in that it tries to coerce an object into a specific type, and raises an error if it fails, but it's quite close.

Usage:

```py
from pydantic import parse_obj_as
from typing import Dict

parse_obj_as(Dict[str, int], {'xxx': 1, 'yyy': 2})
#> {'xxx': 1, 'yyy': 2}

parse_obj_as(Dict[str, int], {'xxx': 1, 123: '12'})
#> {'xxx': 1, '123': 12}

parse_obj_as(Dict[str, int], ['not a dict'])
#> ValidationError: 1 validation error for ParsingModel[Dict[str, int]]
#> __root__
#>   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Docs [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#parsing-data-into-a-specified-type).

Note: I build pydantic, so I'm a little biased.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and thanks for Pydantic - that library is so great! (I seem to find a use for it in every project I do these days...)  This makes it very clear Pydantic's approach, which I interpret as a pragmatic EAFP ("try to instantiate as") rather than strict validation.