# Python - check if variable is a typing type

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there a way to check if a variable is a given typing type?

I mean something like this:

```
def check_type(variable: Any, typing: Any) -> bool:
    return variable is typing


check_type([1, 2, 3], List[int])  # True
check_type([1, 2, 3.4], List[int])  # False
check_type([1, 2, 3.4], List[Union[int, float]])  # True
```

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504010/5404694. Also check out pydantic

Answer (score -1):

There is Python function called type()

i.e.

```
for item_list in list:
    type(item_list)
```

Comment: I was going to give a similar answer when I first saw the question, but what is being asked is more complicated: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html