# Can Rust traits be partially implemented?

Tags: rust

I'm reading the book *Programming Rust*, and learned about Rust's traits and generic types. And I find that type bounds can be placed on the methods of a trait. Then I constructed the following trait and implemented it for a struct.

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;
trait Test<T> {
    fn show(&self)
    where
        T: Display;
    fn test(&self);
}

struct S<T> {
    field: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T> for S<T> {
    fn show(&self)
    where
        T: Display,
    {
        println!("My field: {}", self.field);
    }

    fn test(&self) {
        println!("Just for test");
    }
}
```

The following code does not compile, just as expected:

```rust
struct R;

fn main() {
    let s = S { field: R {} };
    s.show();
}
```

But the following code does compile and run:

```rust
struct R;

fn main() {
    let s = S { field: R {} };
    s.test();
}
```

Shouldn't Rust just reject the code when `s` is defined as `S { field: R{} }`? Does it mean that `s` is an instance of `S` that implements `trait T` partially?

Answer (score 1):

> Can Rust traits be partially implemented?

No. Either all in, or nothing.

But why is one code compiling but the other won't.

The reason is the extra bound on `show`

```rust
fn show(&self) where T: Display;
```

This means, that when you want to call this method, your `T` must implement `Display`. If it's not implemented, you can't call it.

Rusts "generics" work different than C++ for example.

In C++ you have [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) (Substitution failure is not an error). This is kind of [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing).
Rust works on bounds, that means you have to specify what kind of traits a your "generic" must impelement to use the functions. In this case you can call [`Display::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#tymethod.fmt) because you specified, that your `T` must implement that trait.

This bound is not specified for your `test` method and therefore you can call it with whatever type you want.

Comment: It's known that implementing a trait means implementing all its methods. So implementing trait `Test` for `S`, it means both of `test` and `show` are implemented. Why rust accepts an `S` that does not conform all the type bound requirements exposed by `Test`'s methods.

Comment: @shengjiew Correct it has implementation of `show` , otherwise compiler would give an error like `show` method not found for `s`, imo the behavior is not different than [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb2c9c936c8c13d1c88cac67d752a347), function is there but you cannot use for that type.