# How is a Trait different from Duck typing?

Tags: c++, traits, duck-typing

been reading this [article on Traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) in Computer programming.

The opening sentence highlights two points

- Traits both provide a set of methods that implement behaviour to a class,
- and require that the class implement a set of methods that parameterize the provided behaviour.

The *behaviour* that the definition talks about seems to suggest it is duck typing.

I did read [What is duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing) and the following example in C++ helps with that.

```
template <typename T>
void f (T x) {
    x.method ();
}
```

We have effectively parametrized the method 'f' with type 'T'. The fact that it done at compile time and not at runtime shouldn't make a difference.

As highlighted in the Wikipedia [article on Traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) It is not clear to me, how is a trait is different from duck typing ? Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you asking about traits as the term is usually used in C++ metaprogramming, or in the sense of named interfaces in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @DavisHerring the question is in the context of wikipedia article. How is a trait different from duck typing ?

Comment: In essence, traits rely on duck typing. Traits are a particular way, a particular design pattern, of using duck typing.