# Google Apps Script how detect typeof blob?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```js
var data = Utilities.newBlob("THis is blob data", MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, 'test.txt');

if (  ?? ) then Logger.log('yes, this is blob') ;
```

**How to detect data is blob?** (not object)

```js
instanceof Blob
// or
instanceof BlobSource
```

Result: ReferenceError: `Blob` or `BlobSource` is not defined

```js
instanceof GoogleAppsScript.Base.Blob;
// ReferenceError: `GoogleAppsScript` is not defined

typeof data
// result: object

Object.prototype.toString.call(data);
// result: [object Object]
```

Comment: `__proto__.constructor.name === 'Blob'` ?

Comment: And/or `Object.prototype.toString.call(instance) === "[object Blob]"` if the `name` property isn't supported (GAS has a *really* old JS engine, though I hear it's getting updated).

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(data);` result is `[object Object]`

Comment: @HasanudinH.Syafaat - Ah, well... Was worth a try. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing):

```
if (typeof data.copyBlob === 'function')
{
  // it's probably a blob
  console.log('yep');
}
```

Reference: [Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html)

Comment: Looks like the best solution indeed ;) I would just wrap it in a function like this: `const isBlob = obj => 'function' === obj.copyBlob`