# inheritance in python about derived class usage syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname):
        self.fname=fname
        self.lname=lname
    
    def printper(self):
        return self.fname,self.lname

class emp:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,empno):
        self.empno=empno
        person.__init__(self,fname,lname)
    
    def printper(self):
        return self.empno,self.fname,self.lname

e1=emp("john","michael",20)
print(e1.printper())

# output: (20, 'john', 'michael')
```

I am confused - `emp` does not inherit from `person`, but *the code still works*. Why? Calling `person.__init__()` in the `emp.__init__()` seems to make the code work. Is that all that is necessary? Is it not actually mandatory to write `class emp(person):` to have a derived class?

Comment: when i mean expected  like this class emp(person)

Comment: It's hard to understand the question. I think you are trying to point out that the code says `class emp:`, and does not say `class emp(person):`, but it still works. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: You can always call one class from another, even if the calling class isn't derived from the class being called. However, in your case, calling the `person` constructor doesn't do anything, as you never assigned the results to a variable.

Comment: @MattDMo it certainly does do something here, as evidenced by the code reporting those values without any `AttributeError`. There is no reason to "assign the results" from *calling a constructor*, because the result will generally be `None` anyway. The point is that the object passed to the `self` parameter gets modified.

Comment: yes karl you understood the question correctly..

Comment: @Karl okay, I see what's going on. By calling`person`'s `__init__` using `emp`'s `self`, that `self` gets modified to have the `fname` and `lname` attributes.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not care about checking types, inheritance relationships, etc. ahead of time. It only cares what happens when the code is run. [This allows for what is called "duck typing"](/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing):

```
class Employee:
    def fired(self):
        print("Oh no, I have to look for a new job")

class Gun:
    def fired(self):
        print("Bang! Did the bullet hit the target?")

for thing in [Employee(), Gun()]:
    thing.fired()
```

It does not matter that the classes `Employee` and `Gun` have nothing to do with each other, and it does not matter that the purpose of `fired` is completely different. Both of the objects in the list have a method that is **named** `fired`, so the code works without error.

Similarly in your code:

```
class emp:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,empno):
        self.empno=empno
        person.__init__(self,fname,lname)
```

If we call `person.__init__`, then that is *just a function* that we found inside the `person` class - **not** a method that we looked up on an object. This is because we used a class on the left-hand side of `.`, not an instance. That function will happily accept an `emp` instance as the value for `self` - it *does not care* whether that `self` is a `person` instance. It's a user-defined object, so there is no problem setting `fname` and `lname` attributes.

After that, the `printper` method will have no problem finding `fname` and `lname` attributes on the `emp` instance - because they are there.

"So why bother ever inheriting at all, then?"

Because even though this "works", it still doesn't actually make an inheritance relationship. That has some consequences:

- `super` does not work - the `__init__` call had to say explicitly what other class to use, and the code doesn't really make sense. From an outside perspective, it's *sheer coincidence* that it sets the right attributes.
- `isinstance` will not work, by default. `emp` is not in the `__bases__`, nor the `__mro__` of `person`.