# I'm trying to familiarize myself with HTML, and found this in an amazon link. Any idea what it might be?

Tags: html

I'm sure its a dev messing around, but I'm more curious about the second commented out portion. Any ideas on what it might be?

<!-- sp:eh:fNQjP2lah+L7YGnqB2LUts1HpP3bTlUKQP1IE7cH74YXMeygoY8P/8fY+KPiWxKEKcmq0rqI3cQw9JEuc3j7QqOlZL4V0jOcG+K2wRXgLQuS+LtwawZ4UQ== -->

[Here is the link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rteeT.png)

Here is the link to the amazon page. I used ctrl+u to get to the source:

`https://www.amazon.com/Carlie-Outdoor-Sandblast-Finished-Dining/dp/B07CGK4T8R/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=Y5n1j&content-id=amzn1.sym.c4359eaf-cf90-433f-a68d-45a3f5f0d79f&pf_rd_p=c4359eaf-cf90-433f-a68d-45a3f5f0d79f&pf_rd_r=R35GHPAZSDWJRVC8RY1X&pd_rd_wg=lSpyL&pd_rd_r=490ddb98-92f2-41a1-96e8-19f0d0fc0ee0&ref_=pd_gw_pd_pss_gwp_d_0&th=1`

Comment: My guess is it's some kind of easter egg. There's probably a riddle there. It looks like base64 but it decodes to gibberish, so there's more to it. But you're right, definitely a dev screwing around and having a bit of a lark.

Comment: The ascii art implies it has something to do with [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4205130/2813224)