# What feature of what language does Clojure Protocols derive from?

Tags: clojure

What feature of what language does Clojure Protocols derive from?

Note: this is not a question about "How to Use Protocols"

This is a question about what inspired the idea.

In particular, what I want is to get something like:

- XYZ + ABC inspired Clojure Protocols

Then, I can go off and read about directions people went with XYZ and ABC for language features.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know Java, Clojure protocols are similar to Java interfaces - but better. The [Clojure website](http://clojure.org/protocols) says this about protocols (and there's more background information and rationale about protocols on that page):

> - Provide a high-performance, dynamic polymorphism construct as an alternative to interfaces
> - Support the best parts of interfaces
>
>   - specification only, no implementation
>   - a single type can implement multiple protocols
> - While avoiding some of the drawbacks
>
>   - Which interfaces are implemented is a design-time choice of the type author, cannot be extended later (although interface injection might eventually address this)
>   - implementing an interface creates an isa/instanceof type relationship and hierarchy
> - Avoid the 'expression problem' by allowing independent extension of the set of types, protocols, and implementations of protocols on types, by different parties
>
>   - do so without wrappers/adapters
> - Support the 90% case of multimethods (single dispatch on type) while providing higher-level abstraction/organization

Furthermore, you might find [Solving the Expression Problem with Clojure 1.2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-clojure-protocols/) an interesting read:

> Clojure expert Stuart Sierra introduces you to new features in Clojure 1.2 that solve the Expression Problem, a classic programming dilemma. Protocols let you extend preexisting types to new methods, and datatypes let you extend preexisting methods to new types — all without changing the existing code. You'll also see how Java™ interfaces and classes can interact with Clojure protocols and datatypes.

Comment: Note that Java interfaces, in turn, are directly taken from Objective-C protocols (Objective-C was *the* main influence on the design of Java). Objective-C protocols, then, are inspired by the idea of protocols in Smalltalk, which in Smalltalk are purely a documentation convention, which Objective-C turned into a language feature.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, was Clojure Protocols inspired by something, except desire to solve Expression Problem, but Protocols are doing similar thing as Haskell typeclasses, for example...

Look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509782/simple-explanation-of-clojure-protocols) for more information - it also mentions Scala traits