# Type mismatch, expected: T, actual: T

Tags: scala, inheritance, compare, type-parameter

I'm not understanding what this error wants me to do:

```
Type mismatch, expected: T, actual: T
```

I only have 3 lines of code:

```
case class BaseElem[T](e: T)
case class OrderedElem[T <: Ordered](override val e: T) extends BaseElem[T](e) with Ordered[OrderedElem[T]] {
  override def compare(that: OrderedElem[T]): Int = this.e.compare(that.e)
}
```

`BaseElem` is a simple container of `T`'s. `OrderedElem` is an `Ordered` container of `T <: Ordered`. So I want a comparison between `OrderedElem`s to be the comparison of their respective elements.

The error is in the override of `compare`, the code highlighted by the error is `that.e`.

1. What is this error saying and how do I fix it?
2. Side question, can the declaration of `OrderedElem` be simplified and retain the desired semantics?

Comment: Some code smell in your snippet 1) [case classes inheritance is something you should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158929/what-is-so-wrong-with-case-class-inheritance), in fact there will be compiler error for recent scala versions  2) Naming **different** type aliases, in **different** classes with the same `T` letter is the source of errors you had at least 25 other options, pick, say `U` for the alias in `OrderedElem`. Finally, there is also `error: type Ordered takes type parameters` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the part `OrderedElem[T <: Ordered]`. After following om-nom-nom's smell cleanups and fixing the error he noted, I found that types like `Int` (with primitive representations) don't extent `Ordered` in Scala (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385235/how-to-paramaterize-int-as-ordered-in-scala)), so one must use a "view bound" `<%` to tell Scala to also look for available implicit conversions.

Now I have:

```
class BaseElem[T](val e: T)

class OrderedElem[U <% Ordered[U]](override val e: U) extends BaseElem(e) with Ordered[OrderedElem[U]] {
  override def compare(that: OrderedElem[U]): Int = this.e.compare(that.e)
}

object Run extends App {
  val a = new OrderedElem(0)
  val b = new OrderedElem(1)
  println(a < b)  // => true
}
```